# Can't scroll my recycler view to last element

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try to scroll my recycler view to the last element.

When I remove   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" from refresh layout t
en it works fine.

I am not sure why adding   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" causes this issue  but it seems like it makes the swipRefresh layout goes beyond the bottom border

Note: I use recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition to reach to last element

Could anyone tell me how can I fix this issue?

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/left_menu"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:padding="@dimen/space8dp"
                    android:tint="?attr/hamburgerIconTintColor"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    style="@style/SubHeader"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/space32dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_room_members"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/left_menu"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    tools:text="From Jamie Thompson" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_room_members"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:padding="@dimen/space8dp"
                    android:tint="?attr/hamburgerIconTintColor"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_members" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

            <!-- MainView -->


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space16dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                    <!-- Selfies -->

                    <com.selfieyo2.core.utils.customview.ImageSetView
                        android:id="@+id/imv_set"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        tools:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imv_video_icon"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_videocam"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tv_uploading"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:visibility="visible">

                        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:indicatorName="BallScaleMultipleIndicator" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space8dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/space4dp"
                    tools:itemCount="1"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/listitem_other_chat" />

            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space8dp">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_send_media_file"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="@dimen/space8dp"
                android:tint="?attr/hamburgerIconTintColor"
                android:visibleGone="@{isPrivateOrHotRoom}"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chat_attach_file"
                tools:visibility="gone" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_hashtags"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_send_media_file"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="@dimen/space8dp"
                android:tint="?attr/hamburgerIconTintColor"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hashtag" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_chat_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space8dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btn_send"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btn_hashtags"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_chat_bg"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
                android:hint="@string/chat_newmessage_placeholder"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="160"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:minHeight="42dp"
                android:textColor="?attr/chatInputTextColor"
                android:textColorHint="?attr/chatInputTextColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:hint="How are you today ? This is too long text to check the end?" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space8dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/space8dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/space8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space8dp"
                android:tint="?attr/hamburgerIconTintColor"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <!--Empty View -->
        <!--<TextView
            style="@style/SubHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/this_chat_has_no_messages_yet"
            android:visibleGone="@{viewModel.isEmptyList()}" />-->


        <!-- Loading Indicator -->
        <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibleGone="@{viewModel.isProcessing()}" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space8dp"` from your SwipeRefreshLayout instead add bottom margin to your recycler View.

Also change your swipe refresh layout's hieght to wrap content.

Comment: @Khaledqwas so you are using function to scroll to last item. what happen actually ? the list doesn't scroll at all or it scroll but not to the last element ??

Comment: It scrolls but not reaches the last element

Comment: Please check if you have any view above the bottom side of the recycler view, maybe the last item view gets hidden under that view.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to remove `android:clipToPadding="false"` line from `RecyclerView` (and also `paddingBottom`)? this line may cause inproper layouting due to fact that `layout_behavior` set is in fact manipulating padding/position of `View` when it is scrolled (hides/shows Toolbar wrapped in `AppBarLayout`)

Comment: I have tried now but it did not work too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LayoutManager` which is assigned to the `RV` you can use it for scroll to the bottom:

```
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Application.Context);
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
mLinearLayoutManager.ScrollToPosition(array.size() - 1);
```

Comment: can tou please show how you are trying to scroll to the list bottom position?

Comment: I use recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition()

Comment: did you try smth else except this method?

Comment: yes using the layout manager instead. The issue is about app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" because when I remove it I don't have any issue anymore but I lose that animation

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty View as the last element in your recycler View. That helps.